# Refurbishing an old Alienware Laptop

Tags: laptop

I have an old (2011) Alienware m18x. At this point, it is half dead (both dedicated AMD GPUs died long ago) and something is going on with the internal clock, as it keeps delaying the date after being adjusted, and the keyboard is also dead. Other than that, it still works fine, with its ancient SSD, and the screen still looks great.

As I am not very knowledgeable in computer hardware topics, I would like to ask what is the feasibility of completely changing the internals of the Laptop.
By this I do not mean upgrading GPUs, memory and such, but completely removing the internals and using just the body with a completely new set of components (eg. from a newer laptop, where the components would be up to date, but fit in a smaller form factor).

I understand there might be complications, such as thermals, component positioning and so on. I also understand that this might be much more expensive and complicated than just buying a new Laptop. Regardless, would this project be feasible? What would be the basic things to take into account in doing this?

Comment: In a word: no. In a few more words: nearly all laptop motherboards are custom designed, hence ports are in different places, batteries different configs, newer internal probably have entirely different IO etc etc etc. Personally I would only consider this if I could obtain 2 or 3 other identical broken units to cobble together a working one. Even then, laptops aren't modular like desktops, so swapping (motherboard) components is seldom feasible.

Comment: Don't post the same question to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or request migration. Same as your other post, get out your CAD & 3D printer & start taking some measurements.

Comment: @Tetsujin, go nice on him. He's new to Stack Exchange and doesn't know where to post. I didn't know either for a while.

For future advice, I'd look around in the SE sit and see if your question would fit in there. If you post and it doesn't fit, people should give you a suggestion where to put the question. This question fits perfectly here, hence why I created a response below.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some components from dead laptops (ssd, ram, wifi card), but most of them are custom and hard to get out (motherboard, gpu, keyboard, case, screen, mouse, cooler). So I would reccomend getting all working parts out that have a standard layout and use them in your next pc as upgrades (that's how I do it)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually what I had in mind was to do something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Perqf0dOGLk (Video Titled "Building an invisible PC" from the DIY Perks Channel) but instead of doing it inside a "desk" and use big powerful components, to use smaller, laptop-sized components, inside the M18x body (which is somewhat big). I understand ports would be lost as well as some functionality, but would still like to know if it is possible, and how would one go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptop components are not interchangeable, so you can not really take much out of this laptop. I would take out the SSD/HDD and either use it in a new system or sell it if you do not put it in a new system. Regarding the rest of the system, I'd recycle it responsibly by giving it to a computer recycler. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually what I had in mind was to do something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Perqf0dOGLk (Video Titled "Building an invisible PC" from the DIY Perks Channel) but instead of doing it inside a "desk" and use big powerful components, to use smaller, laptop-sized components, inside the M18x body (which is somewhat big). I understand ports would be lost as well as some functionality, but would still like to know if it is possible, and how would one go about it.